# HashSearch and HashInsert functions implementation after Cormen book

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

For my algorithm i need another function called `h(k, i)` I think it's search the hash to see if it's empty and then insert the element on `i` position, but I'm not sure. Can someone explain me that function ? Thank you. Here's my code so far.

```
  #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;
  #define hashSize 1000
  typedef struct hashElem{
      char* date;
      char* holiday;
  }hashElem;

  typedef struct hash{
      struct hashElem element;
      struct hash* next;
  }hash;

  void h(hash* hashTable[hashTable],int index)
  {

  }

  int hashInsert (hash* hashTable[hashSize],int k)
  {
      int index=0,index2;
      do
      {
          index2=h(k,index);
          if (hashTable[index2]== NULL) {
              hashTable[index2] = k;
              return index2;
          }
          else
              index=index+1;
      }
      while (index == hashSize);
      printf ("Hash Table Overflow");
  }
  int hashSearch (hash* hashTable[hashSize],int k){
      int index=0,index2;
      do
      {
          index2=h(k,index);
          if (hash* hashTable[index2]==k)
              return index2;
          index=index+1;
      }
      while (hash* hashTable[index2]==NULL || index=hashSize);
      return NULL;
        }
  int main() {
      cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;
      return 0;
  }
```

Comment: That should not even compile... `hash* hashTable[hashTable]`?

Comment: Could you please add some meaningful client code instead of printing "Hello World"? Apparently you want to map dates to holidays, both represented by strings, but you never pass any strings. Your search function is void, yet returns an index or the null pointer. The hash function `h` doesn't require the hash table; it just needs to determine a hash value from a key. The whole code is full of conceptual errors.

Comment: @Oehm I know it wont work , it's only 10% done . First I wana understand that h function , because without that I can't work and there's no point going further.

Comment: I think you should first make up your mind what the key and value types are. And chosse either C or C++. At the moment, your code is C, except the `<iostream>` stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Your "h function" is a hash function, it takes a key as the input and returns a position of the key in the hash table.

A simple hash function can be `return key % tablesize`.

Apparently such simple hash function may result in different keys having the same position, known as "collisions". Choosing a proper hash function and choosing a way to solve the collisions is a broad topic.

There are some situations when we can find a perfect hash function to avoid collisions, and that's an even harder topic.

Normally in a hash function we don't search the whole hash table and find an empty position to return, because we expect the hash function takes O(1) time.

Comment: Thank you for your help and explanation mate ! I will start to  read more about collisions.

Comment: @HenryLee Yes I agree with you; I just showed the OP a basic Hash Table and to avoid having those collisions, and having to write out the full design of a robust, accurate and efficient hash table, I suggested and highly recommended to the OP to use std::unordered_map!

Comment: @FrancisCugler is right. A map template from STL can be a replacement in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a Hash Table for general demonstration purposes.

**HashMap.h**

```
#ifndef HASH_MAP_H
#define HASH_MAP_H

// ============ Hash Entry ======================
class HashEntry {
private:
    int m_key;
    int m_value;

public:
    HashEntry( int key, int value );

    int getKey() const;
    int getValue() const;
}; // HashEntry

// ========== Hash Map ==========================
class HashMap {
public:
    static const int TABLE_SIZE;

private:
    HashEntry** m_pTable;

public:
    HashMap();
    ~HashMap();

    int  get( int key ) const;
    void insert( int key, int value );

}; // HashMap

#endif // HASH_MAP_H
```

**HashMap.cpp**

```
// ================ Hash Entry ==================
HashEntry::HashEntry( int key, int value ) :
m_key( key ),
m_value( value ) {
} // HashKey

int HashEntry::getKey() const {
    return m_key;
} // getKey

int HashEntry::getValue() const {
    return m_value;
} // getValue

// ================ Hash Map ====================
const int HashMap::TABLE_SIZE = 128;

HashMap::HashMap() {
    m_pTable = new HashEntry*[TABLE_SIZE];

    for ( unsigned u = 0; u < TABLE_SIZE; u++ ) {
        m_pTable[u] = nullptr;
    }
} // HashMap

HashMap::~HashMap() {
    for ( unsigned u = 0; u < TABLE_SIZE; u++ ) {
        if ( m_pTable[u] != nullptr ) {
            delete m_pTable[u];
        }
    }
    delete[] m_pTable;
} // ~HashMap

int HashMap::get( int key ) const {
    int hash = ( key % TABLE_SIZE );

    while ( m_pTable[hash] != nullptr && m_pTable[hash]->getKey() != key ) {
        hash = (hash + 1) % TABLE_SIZE;
    }

    if ( m_pTable[hash] == nullptr ) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return m_pTable[hash]->getValue();
    }
} // get

void HashMap::insert( int key, int value ) {
    int hash = ( key % TABLE_SIZE );

    while ( m_pTable[hash] != nullptr && m_pTable[hash]->getKey() != key ) {
        hash = (hash + 1) % TABLE_SIZE;
    }

    if ( m_pTable[hash] != nullptr ) {
        delete m_pTable[hash];
    }
    m_pTable[hash] = new HashEntry( key, value );
} // insert
```

And here it is in use:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "HashMap.h"

int main() {
    HashMap myHash;

    myHash.insert( 1, 22 );
    myHash.insert( 2, 445 );
    myHash.insert( 3, 12 );
    myHash.insert( 6, 24 );
    myHash.insert( 4, 9 );

    std::cout << "My Hash Table: " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Key: 1 - Value: " << myHash.get( 1 ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Key: 6 - Value: " << myHash.get( 6 ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Key: 4 - Value: " << myHash.get( 4 ) << std::endl;

    return RETURN_OK;
} // main
```

Now you can take this class and change the key and value to any type suitable, but even more to make this reusable and generic; you can easily template this class. Also if you are using a modern compiler, instead of using raw pointers, you can exchange them for smart pointers such as `std::shared_ptr<>` or `std::unique_ptr<>` that way you don't have to worry about memory leaks. However, to take this a step further you can simply just do this in your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

int main() {
     // Normally all of this code within this main function would be
     // a part of a class, I'm just showing a demonstration of how
     // one can use std::unordered_map<> for a Hash Map.
     std::string date;
     std::string holiday;

     typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> HashTable;
     HashTable myTable;

     myTable.insert( HashTable::value_type( "January 1st", "New Years Day" ) );
     myTable.insert( HashTable::value_type( "July 4th", "Fourth of July" ) );
     myTable.insert( HashTable::value_type( "December 25th, "Christmas" ) );

    // Then To Search The Hash Table:
    // Usually This would be in a class's function that returns the value
    // when a specified key was passed in as a parameter.
    HashTable::const_iterator it = myTable.find( "Feburary 14th" );
    if ( it == myTable.cend() ) {
        std::cout << "Date & Holiday not found!";
    } else {
        std::cout << myTable->second;
    }

    // As you can see this is repeat code! 
    // A class that would search a hash table would have 
    // something like this as a member function. 
    HashTable::const_iterator it = myTable.find( "January 1st" );
    if ( it == myTable.cend() ) {
        std::cout << "Date & Holiday not found!";
    } else {
        std::cout << myTable->second;
    }
    // Except for printing out the element they would return the value and
    // in most cases they would return a pointer to an object, this
    // way if it is not found, a nullptr is returned.

    return 0;        
}
```

Comment: @Netheru I edited the original to show how one would use `std::unordered_map` in the same way as a has table.

Comment: @Netheru yes I would highly suggest using std::unordered_map